# disable carousel advance buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a carousel with 3 panes controlled by left and right arrows. I want the left arrow to disable on pane 1 and the right arrow to disable on pane 3, so the carousel doesn't loop round itself.

I have written a button disable function that appears to work, but won't when I try to call it from the correct pane.

Here is the javascript which advances the carousel pane, called on the right arrow button click:

```
if(currentPane==1){

        currentPane=2;

        $("#carouselDots").css('background-image', 'url(images/dots_2.png)');   
}
else if(currentPane==2){

        currentPane=3;

        $("#carouselDots").css('background-image', 'url(images/dots_3.png)');

        disableRButton();               
}
```

here is the disableRButton function:

```
function disableRButton()
{
    $("#carouselBtn").button("disable");
}
```

I also want the button to change its BG img when disabled this is what i'm trying to do in CSS:

```
.carouselBtn:disabled{
background:transparent url('images/carouselArrowDisabled.png')no-repeat;}
```

Any Ideas on why the button is not disabling would be great. Also, what is the correct way to use this disabled button tag in CSS, or is it better to change the button's BG img in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think jquery has a button function that takes a string saying disabled. You need to add a disabled attribute to the button to disable it.

For example

```
$("my-button").attr("disabled", true);
```

You are using the :disabled selector correctly, but the first part of the selector is wrong I think. It should start with a `.` if carouselBtn is the name of a class of `#` if it is the name of the ID. You currently mix these in your different examples.

Comment: works now, including the :disabled selector in the css changing the BG img. The issue was not only my syntax for disabling the button but also the fact i was using # rather than . when calling it. The disable function now reads: $(".carouselBtn").attr("disabled",true);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [jQuery UI Button Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/), you have to do it this way:

`$("#carouselBtn" ).button({disabled:true});`

Most likely it will work when you write `"disabled"` instead of `"disable"`.

Answer (score 0):

you set attr disable thats enough to avoid the clicks after using jquery to set background

```
function disableRButton()
{
    $("#carouselBtn").attr("disabled",true);
    $("#carouselBtn").css("background-image",'images/carouselArrowDisabled.png');
}
```

Comment: thanks, this was very close to correct the $("#carouselBtn") had to be $(".carouselBtn") - due to my incorrect naming!